# how does KVM virtualize performance counter (PMC)?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm

I am using **KVM-QEMU** in Intel platform.
And I am wondering how is the **PMC/PMU** being virtualized in **KVM**?

My understanding of vPMC is as follows.

Since PMU is a shared physical resource, so hypervisor shall context save/restore PMC configurations and counters during VMExit/VMEnter.

But in my testing, I got confused.

```
 (In my host Linux, the MSR of IA32_PERF_FIXed_CTRL is set to 0xb0)
```

First of all, in a launched VM,

I `'wrmsr IA32_PERF_FIXed_CTRL 0x0b`', to enable `FIXed_CTR0` in VM.
Then, I logged the MSR of IA32_PERF_FIXed_CTRL at VMExit, and found FIXed_CTR0 is not enabled.

I think it is because when VMExit happens, it is already in the host context, so the MSR of IA32_PERF_FIXed_CTRL is the one of host, not the host.

But the question is where is that MSR for the VM being saved in host, and when and where the VM's MSR is being restored to CPU during VMEnter???

Hope my question is clear.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

KVM implements a virtual PMU that utilizes Linux's perf subsystem for core PMU operations. It does not expose the host PMU directly to the guest.

When you do `wrmsr IA32_PERF_FIXed_CTRL 0x0b`, you are not writing to the hardware MSR (Model-specific register), KVM traps the MSR write and makes an update in its representation of the virtual PMU. Look for `kvm_set_msr_common()` in `x86.c`, this will ultimately call `intel_pmu_set_msr()` in `pmu_intel.c` that does the real magic. Also look at `struct kvm_pmu()` which is KVM's representation of the PMU.

The MSR doesn't need to be restored like typical VMCS fields because KVM saves guest specific PMU settings in `struct kvm_pmu()` per vCPU (`struct kvm_vcpu`).

Comment: Thank Bandan for the reply, I got better understanding of vPMU.
As you said KVM trap the access to control MSR of PMU, how about the counter MSR?
I mean when the guest is running in non-root mode, how does the counter work in a _precise_ mode?
For example, if guest tries to count the 'retired instructions', it then needs to read MSR 0x309 (FIXed_CTR_0), how does KVM emulate the 'retired instructions'?
Thanks,

Comment: KVM does not "emulate" the PMC. It just exposes a virtual PMC to the guest. The PMC subsystem uses perf for tasks on behalf of the guest. For example, check pmc_read_counter() and how it utilizes the perf core function perf_event_read_value() to read a counter on behalf of the guest. For a co-relation of how the perf core is utlized, think of a user process such as the perf command that hooks into the kernel perf functions to utilize the PMC.

Comment: Thanks to Bandan's answer, I got more closer to the final target.
As you said, the PMC hardware is NOT exposed to VM, all the PMC access is trapped and emulated by host perf. My understanding (maybe wrong, correct me please) is the host and guest are running mutual exclusively, so if guest is running, perf in host should NOT run. If it is true, there must be something _magical_ happened when VMExit to host. To be more specific, I want to figure out how perf in host can count the 'instruction ran' in guest. (I will add printk to try to figure out the magics).
I voted for your answers.