# Event "cache-misses" not supported by perf in aws

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, perf

I am having trouble running perf on aws(Ubuntu 14.04.4) . It seems that none of the hardware events are supported. Any idea what's going on? I am using a dedicated instance.

Here's an example:

```
$ perf stat sleep 4

 Performance counter stats for 'sleep 4':

          0.388772 task-clock (msec)         #    0.000 CPUs utilized          
                 1 context-switches          #    0.003 M/sec                  
                 0 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
               179 page-faults               #    0.460 M/sec                  
   <not supported> cycles                  
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend
   <not supported> instructions            
   <not supported> branches                
   <not supported> branch-misses           

       4.000773655 seconds time elapsed
```

Perf version:

```
$ perf version
perf version 3.13.11-ckt39
```

Kernel version:

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-92-generic
```

Comment: This is of course off-topic for [so], but I guess the answer would be -- AMIs are not real machines, so "hardware" events don't make much sense.

Comment: There are [two kinds](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html) of VMs in EC2, Hardware Virtual Machine (HVM) and Paravirtual (PV).  The type of VM is an attribute of the AMI you use to launch the VM and the instance type (most instance types support only one virtualization type, but a few support both).  You might experience different behavior on one compared to the other.  Please consider removing this question from Stack Overflow, and posting instead to sister-site [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), where it is (I suspect) more on-topic.

Comment: Check http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-05-04/the-pmcs-of-ec2.html = "PMCs available in EC2, which are for dedicated hosts only (eg, m4.16xl, i3.16xl)" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763070)